# How to route from ELB to the running instance (Total two EC2 instances)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elb

Currently, I am using two `ec2` instances, in case one goes down other will keep alive.

In order to do this:

1. Created `ELB` where I route to the target group.
2. Inside the target group I have registered two `ec2` instances.

However, when one of the servers goes down, it keeps randomly switching between two `ec2` instances. The health of the server is reported as fine even though the jar program is dead inside. Is there a way to check when the program inside is dead and then always route to the working instance?

Comment: Your heath checks must be incorrectly setup.

Comment: I agree with Marcin, can you please share it how you configured the healthcheck within the TargetGroup?

Comment: `Is there a way to check when the program inside is dead and then always route to the working instance?` - the other comments mention them already but this is exactly what HealthChecks are for

Comment: Thank you,  worked after configuring health check  correctly